# maximum size for input field name?

Tags: html

Two quick questions:

1. What is the maximum size for the `name` element on an HTML hidden input field that is used in a form that is submitted using POST?
2. What is the maximum size for the `value` element on a hidden HTML input field used in a form that is submitted using POST?

Comment: Strange why this was given a -1... Even if the w3 specifications did state a limit, the *real world* isn't bound to specifications.. I think it's a good question. +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the specs, there is no documented limit, however PHP may limit you according to the `max_file_size` or other  properties in php.ini. That's usually over 5MB though, so I wouldn't be worried.

Answer (score 5):

The specification does not impose limits. You would have to test on a browser-by-browser basis (or work on the "Just don't be stupid" principle).

If you have enough data for it to be significant then you are probably better off caching it on the server (assuming you are populating the hidden inputs there and not with JS) and giving the browser a token instead.

Comment: + 1 for "Just don't be stupid", if only that worked for users ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your webserver may have a configured limit for POST data size. There is no limit specified by HTTP or HTML.